# pig - parsing string with regex

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I'm stuck on string parsing in Pig.

I have looked at the documentation around `regex_extract` and `regex_extract_all` and hoped to use one of those functions.

I have file `'/logs/test.log'`:

```
cat '/logs/test.log'
user=242562&friend=6226&friend=93856&age=35&friend=35900
```

I want to extract the `friend` tags from the url, and in this case, I have 3 identical tags. `regex_extract` seems to only work for the first instance, which is what I expected, and for `regex_extract_all`, it seems like I have know the whole string pattern, which changes on each row of the source file.

It looked ok with `regex_extract`, but this option only gives me the first one.

```
 [root@test]# pig -x local
 A = LOAD './test.log';
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT($0, 'friend=([0-9]*)',1);
 dump B;
 (6226)
```

The examples I see for `regex_extract_all` show regex where you seek out all the tags:

```
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0, 'user=([0-9]+?)&friend=([0-9]+?)&friend=([0-9]+?)&.+?'));
 dump B;
 (242562,6226,93856)
```

That seems to work, but I really just want to extract the friends - (6226,93856,35900).  I also have cases where there might be more-than or less-than 3 friends per user.

Any ideas?

Also looking at using something like `FLATTEN(TOKENIZE($0,'&'))` and then somehow only filtering on the `SUBSTRING($0,0,INDEXOF($0,'=')) == 'friend'` or something like that, but wanted to see if anyone knew a good regex approach.

Comment: Kinda gave up on this and just used STREAM to a quick script I put together.  Didn't want to have to maintain yet another script, but much, much quicker solution. Regret spending so much time trying to get it to work natively

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by simple string manipulations:

```
inputs = LOAD 'input' AS (line: chararray);
tokenized = FOREACH inputs GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line, '&')) AS parameter;
filtered = FILTER tokenized BY INDEXOF(parameter, 'friend=') != -1;
result = FOREACH filtered GENERATE SUBSTRING(parameter, 7, (int)SIZE(parameter)) AS   friend_number;
DESCRIBE tokenized;
DUMP tokenized;
DESCRIBE filtered;
DUMP filtered;
DESCRIBE result;
DUMP result;
```

result:

```
tokenized: {parameter: chararray}
(user=242562)
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(age=35)
(friend=35900)
filtered: {parameter: chararray}
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(friend=35900)
result: {friend_number: chararray}
(6226)
(93856)
(35900)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = LOAD '/logs/test.log' USING PigStorage('&') as (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(f2,'friend=([0-9]*)', 1), 
                       REGEX_EXTRACT(f3,'friend=([0-9]*)', 1),
                       REGEX_EXTRACT(f5,'friend=([0-9]*)', 1);
DUMP b;
```